# I am dealing with WndClass=TElTreeView. How to click on nodes inside it? TestComplete identifies it as a whole

Tags: javascript, automation, jscript, testcomplete

I am writing descriptive programming code for a propriety application in Smartbear's TestComplete automation Tool.

I need help with `WndClass=TElTreeView`. There are multiple nodes or values (displayed as a text) listed inside this tree area.
Object Spy only identify this tree area as a whole and not identifying the different nodes inside it.

My task is to click on different nodes inside this tree area. How can I click on a particular node?
Here is the Scenario of clicking on Nodes in a Tree-Like Structure that I am talking about.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of object Spy view in `TestComplete` for `TElTreeView` Property.

[image]

Recorded scripts works fine and clicks on the recorded node using specific coordinates [Click(77, 44)]. But these node might get changed and therefore coordinates are not fixed.

How to click on different nodes inside it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample code that shows how to work with this control in this article:
[Work with the TElTreeView control](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/26318/)

Please note that you, most probably, need to have debug information for your application and the control to make this sample works. Information on how to compile a VCL application with debug information for TestComplete can be found in the [Preparing Delphi Applications for Testing](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/68476/) article.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for the info. Could you help with more specific info. I checked the link you sent but not able to solve my problem. I hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Prakhar, the current version of TestComplete does not have native support for this control. So, you will be unable to record high-level actions with the tree control anyhow. The only way to work with the control is using its native methods and properties and specified in the article I mentioned. In this case, you will have to create tests that work with the tree control manually - write code that calls script routines from the sample.